# Rebar dependencies via http proxy

Tags: proxy, erlang, rebar

I have a rebar.config that contains this deps entry:

`{cowboy, ".*", {git, "http://github.com/extend/cowboy.git", {branch, "master"}}}`

An when I run "rebar compile" I get this:

`Dependency not available: cowboy-.* ({git,
                                      "http://github.com/extend/cowboy.git",
                                      {branch,"master"}})`

I believe this is because I'm behind a firewall and my only way to access the Internet is through a http proxy. Is there a way to setup rebar to use a http proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that rebar uses git for fetching the dependencies when the deps tuple containts `{git, "http://..."}`. So I solved this by adding this in `.gitconfig`:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://myproxy-url.com:8080
```